# Time an event using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trigger an event on a website, say 30 seconds after someone hits the site, even if they move between pages, or would that require some server side coding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too clumsy for me to want to call it an "answer", but you could add a query string argument to all of your internal links with the remaining time on the time, and have the script start a new timer, picking up the remaining time from the parameter.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I've gone with the localStoage/sessionStorage as the answer. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Good, because that looks like a much better idea to me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use session storage to accomplish this. Javascript Storage data persists across pages and refreshes. Here is some info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```
// SET THIS ON THE FIRST VISIT. CHECK IF ALREADY SET.
if(typeOf(localStorage.getItem('timer')) == 'undefined'){
  localStorage.setItem("timer", "0");
}

setInterval(function(){ 
  //  ADD 1 SECOND TO SESSION TIMER
  localStorage.setItem("timer", localStorage.getItem("timer")++);

  if(localStorage.getItem("timer") == 30){
    // TRIGGER YOUR EVENT ON 30 SECONDS
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is great. Had to tweak the script a bit, but this looks ideal. I'm going to use sessionStorage because it makes more sense for my usage. Thanks again.