# How to prevent my timer from resetting when browser is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make my timer not reset when the browser is refreshed?

I use `blog=blogger`

My problem here is when I press refresh the timer restarts to its original time. How can I make the timer not reset when I click refresh button or when I close the browser?

Here is example 1 : http://topbitcoinfaucet2.blogspot.com

Please give me example. Sorry I'm newbie at javascript.

```js
function secondsTimeSpanToHMS(s) {
 var h = Math.floor(s/3600);
 s -= h*3600;
 var m = Math.floor(s/60);
 s -= m*60;
 return h+":"+(m < 10 ? '0'+m : m)+":"+(s < 10 ? '0'+s : s);
}
$(function() {

 $(".flink").click(function() {
  var timer = $(this).parent().parent().find('.timer');
  if(timer.data('secleft') <= 0) {
   timer.data('secleft', timer.data('minutes') * 60 + 20);
 $(this).parent().fadeTo(300,0.3);
 
  }
 });
 var lasttime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
 var curtime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
 function timer(){
  curtime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
  $(".timer").each(function(){
   if($(this).data('secleft') > 0) {
    $(this).data('secleft', $(this).data('secleft') - (curtime - lasttime));
    $(this).text(secondsTimeSpanToHMS($(this).data('secleft')));
   } else {
    if($(this).text()!=$("#language").data('ready')) {
     $(this).text($("#language").data('ready'));
     $(this).parent().prev().fadeTo(300,1);
     $(this).parent().prev().prev().fadeTo(300,1);
    }
   }
  });
  lasttime = curtime;
  setTimeout(timer, 1000);
 }
 timer();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV CLASS="box" STYLE="width:100%"><TABLE STYLE="width:100%"><TR><TH STYLE="width:220px">link</TH><TH STYLE="width:140px">foryou</TH><TH STYLE="width:140px">Timer</TH><TH/></TR><TR><TD><A CLASS="flink" HREF="https://www.google.com" TARGET="_blank">mylink</A></TD><TD>hi</TD><TD><SPAN CLASS="timer" data-minutes="1" data-secleft="0">Ready</SPAN></TD></TR><TR><TD><A CLASS="flink" HREF="https://www.google.com" TARGET="_blank">mylink</A></TD><TD>hi</TD><TD><SPAN CLASS="timer" data-minutes="1" data-secleft="0">Ready</SPAN></TD></TR>
</TABLE></DIV>
```

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the timer on the server side, in a cookie, or in localStorage.

Comment: Please give me example. Sorry I'm newbie at javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to save either the time when the link was clicked or the time you count down to. See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/flocsy/moecr2xn/2/

```js
function secondsTimeSpanToHMS(s) {
 var h = Math.floor(s/3600);
 s -= h*3600;
 var m = Math.floor(s/60);
 s -= m*60;
 return h+":"+(m < 10 ? '0'+m : m)+":"+(s < 10 ? '0'+s : s);
}
$(function() {
 $(".flink").click(function() {
  var timer = $(this).parent().parent().find('.timer');
  var id = timer.data('id');
  if(timer.data('secleft') <= 0) {
   timer.data('secleft', timer.data('minutes') * 60 + 20);
   $(this).parent().fadeTo(300,0.3);
  }
  // here you need to calculate the timestamp of the time you count down to and save it.
  // note that you'll have to save it per link!
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  var ts = now + (parseInt(timer.data('minutes')) * 60 + 20)*1000;
console.log(ts, now, ts-now);
  localStorage.setItem('timestamp_' + id, ts);
 });
 var lasttime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
 var curtime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
 function timer(){
  curtime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
  $(".timer").each(function(){
   if($(this).data('secleft') > 0) {
$(this).data('secleft', $(this).data('secleft') - (curtime - lasttime));
$(this).text(secondsTimeSpanToHMS($(this).data('secleft')));
   } else {
if($(this).text()!=$("#language").data('ready')) {
 $(this).text($("#language").data('ready'));
 $(this).parent().prev().fadeTo(300,1);
 $(this).parent().prev().prev().fadeTo(300,1);
}
   }
  });
  lasttime = curtime;
  setTimeout(timer, 1000);
 }

  // when loading the page check if for any .flink we already
  // saved a timer before the refresh:
  $(".timer").each(function(){
var timer = $(this);
var id = timer.data('id');
var ts = localStorage.getItem('timestamp_' + id);
var now = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log(id, ts, now, ts-now);
if (ts && ts > now) {
   // if found, we set the secleft of the timer by calculating
   // how much time is 'till the countdown
   var secleft = Math.round((ts - now)/1000);
console.log("secleft:",secleft);
   timer.data('secleft', secleft);
}
  });
  timer();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV CLASS="box" STYLE="width:100%">
 <TABLE STYLE="width:100%">
  <TR><TH STYLE="width:220px">link</TH><TH STYLE="width:140px">foryou</TH><TH STYLE="width:140px">Timer</TH><TH/></TR>
  <TR><TD><A CLASS="flink" HREF="https://www.google.com" TARGET="_blank">mylink</A></TD><TD>hi</TD><TD><SPAN CLASS="timer" data-id="id1" data-minutes="1" data-secleft="0">Ready</SPAN></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD><A CLASS="flink" HREF="https://www.google.com" TARGET="_blank">mylink</A></TD><TD>hi</TD><TD><SPAN CLASS="timer" data-id="id2" data-minutes="1" data-secleft="0">Ready</SPAN></TD></TR>
</TABLE></DIV>
```

In general I would suggest not to depend on the time elapsed since the last time the timer was called, but to calculate the time still left.

Comment: i refreshed and timer reset

Comment: It's probably because it starts the time from the data-minutes printed in the html. I moved the call to timer(); to after I set the data tags from the local storage. I hope it helps. I can't test the refresh here in the snippet

Comment: Timer doesn't start when I click on mylink, it just goes to Google.com

Comment: @sabrys56, you were right, now i made a demo in jsfiddle and found the error, I had to multiply the seconds by 1000 to make them milliseconds for the timestamps. now it works. You can even close the browser and reopen, it continues to count down

Comment: thank you this work
I can ask question for rating
i need rating like mybitcoinfaucets.com
 in my blog

Comment: thank you this work but in counting ended i get -1:59:59 or 0:00:00 not Ready 
I can ask question for rating
i need rating like mybitcoinfaucets.com
 in my blog

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript Local Storage to do this. This is pasted from another answer I posted here: [Time an event using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221737/time-an-event-using-javascript-jquery/35221882#35221882)

---

> You can use session storage to accomplish this. Javascript Storage
>   data persists across pages and refreshes. Here is some info:
>   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```
// SET THIS ON THE FIRST VISIT. CHECK IF ALREADY SET.
if(typeOf(localStorage.getItem('timer')) == 'undefined'){
  localStorage.setItem("timer", "0");
}

setInterval(function(){ 
  //  ADD 1 SECOND TO SESSION TIMER
  localStorage.setItem("timer", localStorage.getItem("timer")++);

  if(localStorage.getItem("timer") == 30){
    // TRIGGER YOUR EVENT ON 30 SECONDS
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: while I agree that localstorage is the way, this code doesn't solve the problem, because it stores the timer (milliseconds until next call to the callback), but it doesn't take into account when was the window refreshed (or was it closed and browser restarted after 10 seconds?)

Comment: @Gavriel I agree that this won't take in to account the instances you mentioned, and time may be lost - however, the problem at hand was preventing the timer from resetting, not loosing time.

Comment: @sabrys56 The code might need tweaking a little bit for your personal circumstance - I've provided a link to more information about session storage - you can use the information learned there to make this code applicable to your situation.

Comment: If you needed to track the time lost when the page was refreshed or the browser closed, you could store the current time along with the timer and calculate the difference between then and now and add it to the timer.

Comment: this site usa timer code http://www.mybitcoinfaucets.com/ ineed usa this code for my blog

Answer (score 0):

I Guess the best Solution would be to save the Value of the Timer on the Server side.

If you want to do it in Javascript saving the value of the Timer to a cookie is a possible soulution.

You can read a cookie

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

And write to cookie

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe";
```

Have a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Hope that helps.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can try to save your timer in local storage before page refresh.

```
$(function() {

    var timer = window.localStorage.getItem('timer') || 0;

    // some stuff with your timer

    $(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
        window.localStorage.setItem('timer', timer)
    });
});
```

Comment: not very accurate. you don't know how much time it takes the browser to refresh

Comment: this site usa timer code mybitcoinfaucets.com ineed usa this code for my blog